# Progress Bar does not update Immediately

Tags: java, windows, swt, progress-bar

I am attempting to use **both a Progress Bar and a Label** to show the **progress** of a discreet number of operations.  Every time I update both, **the label updates immediately, while the progress bar has a noticeable delay before it changes**.

I have a test dialog where, when I press a button, I update both the label and the progress bar to reflect an increase of 1.  This happens immediately in the code without any loops or threads being called (**eliminating any threading-related issues as being the cause**) - just a simple changing of values.  When this happens, the Label updates immediately, while the Progress Bar waits for about half a second before updating visually.  This leads to instances where it will say, for instance, "2 out of 3" when it briefly but noticably shows 1/3 of the bar filled.

[image]

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;

public class ProgressBarTest extends Shell {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Label lblXOfX;
    private Button btnGo;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Display display = Display.getDefault();
            ProgressBarTest shell = new ProgressBarTest(display);
            shell.open();
            shell.layout();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ProgressBarTest(Display display) {
        super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
        createContents();
    }

    protected void createContents() {
        setText("SWT Application");
        setSize(450, 300);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());

        progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, SWT.NONE);
        progressBar.setMaximum(3);
        progressBar.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        lblXOfX = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        lblXOfX.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        lblXOfX.setText("x of x");

        btnGo = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnGo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                go();
            }
        });
        btnGo.setText("Go");
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }

    protected void go() {

        int iCur = progressBar.getSelection();
        iCur++;
        if (iCur > progressBar.getMaximum())
            iCur = 0;

        progressBar.setSelection(iCur);
        lblXOfX.setText(String.format("%s of %s", iCur, progressBar.getMaximum()));
    }

}
```

This occurs despite using the Progress Bar's internal variable to keep track of the value, and using that value to update the label.

Notably, **changing the progress bar's "State" property** to "ERROR" or "PAUSED" eliminates the issue.

Is this some sort of bug with animation?  **Is this just an issue with a specific version of Windows**, such as the Windows 7 that I am using?  Or is it something else?

Comment: It's hard to tell with only a partial snippet what's going on here - can you provide a more complete example (that we can compile and run ourselves) to demonstrate the problem? (see http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Chris Very well, it is done.

Comment: @Chris I can actually make this much simpler.  I am going to rework the whole question.

Comment: I would guess that it is related to the animation used in the `ProgressBar` on Windows 7, because the other states aren't animated. Furthermore, your code works perfectly on Linux. You can post a bug report [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/bugs.php) to let the developers know.

Comment: Also works fine on Mac OS X. The Windows version of `ProgressBar.setSelection` does have some code that says it is trying to deal with an issue that sounds rather like this but it is only done if the state is not Normal - which may be be why it works on the Error and Paused state. Their fix just does the selection again so maybe calling `setSelection` twice would work!

Comment: @greg-449 Good call, the comment states: "Bug in Vista. For some reason, when the progress bar is not in a normal state, it shows the selection of previous call to `PBM_SETPOS`. This is undocumented. The fix is to call `PBM_SETPOS` a second time." So it seems to be that way to fix an issue with Vista... Should definitely be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: @Baz Good work guys.  Please give this information as an answer with references and details, and we'll be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this may be a bug in the Windows version of `ProgressBar` as the code works on Linux and Mac OS X.

The Windows version of `ProgressBar.setSelection` does have some code that says it is trying to deal with an issue that sounds like this but it is only done if the state is not Normal - which may be be why it works on the Error and Paused state. Their fix just does the selection again so maybe calling `setSelection` twice would work!

Comment: I have tried doing setSelection twice in a row, to no avail.  Is there a further trick to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJobs/article.html), it describes how you can make Eclipse Jobs in order to execute long jobs apart of the EDT, and just updates the state of your components.
Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: It is unlikely that this tutorial will help - unless otherwise noted, this is not caused by either threading or a lack of threading.  In fact, the reason threading is not shown here is the entire point.  IF you feel otherwise, please elaborate in greater detail

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the code provided by you using the lasted version of SWT (4.3 Final Release - 5 June 2013) under Windows 7 SP 1 and Windows XP SP3. In both cases the progress bar updated without delay. Maybe an update of the SWT library will help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem a few weeks ago, when using a bargraph to show the progress of ~500 operations completed consecutively. I found that the processes were finished much before the bargraph had even got halfway. I used the code below as a work around:

```
bargraph.value = (Target + 1)
bargraph.value = (Target)
```

Where bargraph is the name of your object, and target is where you want it to move to.

Because the bargraph has a graphical aspect, the marquee effect, it takes time to catch up.
Even though the graphical side could be showing a value of 50, the actual bargraph.value could be 60! By setting the value to a level, and then reducing it by one, the bargraph instantly(ish) updates the graphical side.

**EDIT**

As the comment below shows, the answer above may not work when you are trying to set the value to maximum.

Now, i havent tried this but i think something along the lines of below would work:

```
if (bargraph.value <> Target) then
   if (Target = bargraph.maximumvalue) then
      bargraph.maximumvalue = Target + 1
      bargraph.value = (Target + 1)
      bargraph.value = (Target)
      bargraph.maximumvalue = Target
   else
      bargraph.value = (Target + 1)
      bargraph.value = (Target)
   end if
else
end if
```

As i said, untested, but the principle should work.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I noticed this too.  Will this work in the case when Target is the maximum, however?

Comment: I cant remember the exact error, but i imagine you would get an error similar to accessing the X + 1 index of an array with size X.

Not tried this, but if you tried the edit above, it may work